# if statement evaluates an integer in stream cipher leviathan source code

Tags: c, if-statement, encryption, bit-manipulation

I currently am trying to study a source code of leviathan stream cipher.
Unfortunately, there are a blocks of code which i don't understand.

here's the first one :

```
if (i & leaf_number) {

  g(x, y, z, L->F);  /* right */

}
```

what i don't understand is, why does the original coder use `i & leaf_number` for the `if (statements)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using C's implicit rule that zero is `false`, and non-zero is `true`.

So, read it as:

```
if((i & leaf_member) != 0)  /* Any of leaf_member's 1-bits also 1 in i? */
```

In other words, the `if` is taken if *any* of the bit(s) in the bitmask `leaf_member` is currently set in `i`.

Hopefully only *one* bit is set in `leaf_member`, the test is then naturally for that bit only. If there are multiple bits, the comparison should be:

```
if((i & leaf_member) == leaf_member) /* All of leaf_member's 1-bits 1 in i? */
```

Comment: Great explanation ! Well i have updated my question, can you help me with those ?

Comment: @Bondle No, you **really** shouldn't re-open a question and totally change it after you've accepted an answer. Move that to a **new** question, please!

Comment: Sorry, i'm quite new to this forum. When i try to open a new one, there's a message saying i can only ask a new question after 90 minutes. That's why i re-open this question instead. Do you know any way i can do beside waiting for 90 minutes ?

Comment: @Bondle; You need to wait 90 minutes.

Comment: I see, i guess there's nothing i can do then.
Sorry for the bother guys

Answer (score 0):

Probably he wants to call `g` only if bit-wise `AND` of `i` and  `leaf_number` is `true`, i.e `1`it checks whether the condition is non zero.

Comment: I see. Well i actually also try to re-write the code using java, but java seems don't recognize this kind of statement. Maybe you know why ?

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say that the bitwise AND is 1, since the operation evaluates as an integer.